# What does it mean to order the eigen vectors?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I was working on a task that required me to compute the [Eigenfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenface). To compute the Eigenfaces, it is required to compute the [Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors).

I computed the eigenvalues and eigenvectors using [numpy's eigh](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eigh.html) function. I think I understand what are eigenvectors. They are the vectors that do not change position when an image is transformed from one geometry/plane to another. In that they are able to uniquely identify an image. Eigenvalues correspond to each eigenvector which represent the scalar changes the eigenvector has undergone.

What I do not understand is a statement from [numpy's documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eigh.html) that says:

> The function returns the eigenvalues in ascending order, each repeated according to its multiplicity.

What is this thing about ordering? What order does the documentation refer to?

For example:

```
arr = np.random.uniform(size=(3,3,3))
eigen_val, eigen_vec = np.linalg.eigh(arr)
```

The eigen vectors returned from my above run looks like:

```
  array([[[ 0.73988841,  0.42234431, -0.52363195],
        [ 0.00792645, -0.78378814, -0.62097771],
        [-0.67268292,  0.45530367, -0.58326346]],

    [[-0.57948585,  0.3848149 , -0.7184105 ],
        [-0.32564468, -0.91740718, -0.22873479],
        [ 0.74709551, -0.10139798, -0.6569374 ]],

    [[-0.77375832,  0.50124139, -0.38736951],
        [-0.12305613, -0.7187746 , -0.68426622],
        [ 0.62141392,  0.48178849, -0.61783865]]])
```

What do I interpret from the ordering here?

The whole context is that Eigenvectors are computed during [PCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) and I read that top K eigenvectors explain the best variance. But I could not understand what it meant.

Comment: I think of eigen value as how much information the corresponding vector has. eigen_val[0] / sum(eigen_val) gives you a percentage of information that particular eigen_vector has.

Comment: They are ordered with respect to their corresponding eigenvalues.

Comment: @D_Serg I know but what does it mean to order the eigen values / vectors?

Comment: The eigenvalues returned by `eigh` are real numbers, so the ordering is just the usual numerical ordering (i.e. sorting).  E.g. the numbers [1, 3, 19, 21] are in increasing order.

Comment: I hope I understand your question correctly. The reason why it's ordered is because the eigenvectors that corresponds to larger values of eigenvectors are somewhat "more important", since along that direction, the data has the highest variance. Maybe check this [link](https://skymind.ai/wiki/eigenvector), especially under the titla PCA

Answer (score 0):

They are ordered by eigenvalue magnitude in ascending order, just as the documentation explains:

```
print(eigen_val)

array([[-0.65484945,  0.53345853,  1.2783374 ],
       [-0.54451155,  0.23566298,  1.32844171],
       [-0.11539487,  0.49887717,  1.55005921]])
```

The eigenvalues with the smallest magnitude are listed first, and those with the largest magnitude are listed last. Each eigenvalue has a corresponding eigenvector, and so the order of the eigenvectors is fixed once the eigenvalues are ordered.

Comment: What does it mean to order the eigenvectors?

Comment: To place them in a sequence based on some criteria. In this case, they are ordered to match their corresponding eigenvalues, which are sorted in ascending order by magnitude.

Comment: Eigenvalues and eigenvectors are **paired results** from the eigenvalue solution. Each eigenvalue represents a solution to the eigenvalue problem. The eigenvector is calculated from the eigenvalue, so there is a 1:1 correspondence. So, the first eigenvalue above `eigen_val[0]=-0.65484945` corresponds to your first eigenvector array `eigen_vec[:,:,0]`, and similarly for the second value/vector and so on.